# Access S3 directly from apigateway using SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I'm using SAM to create a cloudformation template. But Now I need access S3 from apigateway and I can't find a way to do it with SAM.

with Cloudformation I can create a AWS::ApiGateway::Resource and AWS::ApiGateway::Method with AWS Integration to achieve it but it has an issue when deploy because I'm mixing ApiGateway and SAM. I would like to avoid migrate the template to OpenAPI definition for just one endpoint.

So is there a way to accomplish it with SAM?

Comment: I haven't worked too much with SAM, but you could try to [export your existing API using the Open API spec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html) and use that as the basis for your new template - this is just a guess though.

Comment: This already discussed in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60488172/sam-template-for-aws-api-gateway-integration-with-s3-as-aws-service

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code for your template